# Not able to change the value of a Dictionary's key

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary

I wanted to count the number of repeated characters in a text file..

I wrote this code

```
foreach(char c in File.ReadAllText(path))
{
    if(dic.ContainsKey(c))
    {
        int i=dic[c];
        dic[c]=i++;
    }
    else
    {
        dic.Add(c,1);
    }
}
```

It's adding all the unique words but it's showing value for all keys as `1` even if there are repeated characters!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want:

```
dic[c] = i + 1;
```

Or possibly, although IMHO this just adds complexity since you don't use `i` after:

```
dic[c] = ++i;
```

---

Explanation:

`i++` is a *post-increment* operation. This means it assigns the *current value* of `i` to `dic[c]` *and then* increments `i`. So in summary, you're always reading in `i=1`, putting the `i=1` back into the dictionary, then incrementing `i` to `2` before sending it to the void.

---

Addendum:

You don't really need to go through a temporary variable at all. You can simply read and assign the value back in one operation with `dic[c] += 1;` or even increment it with `dic[c]++;`.

Comment: ahh...am feeling dumb..:)

Comment: @NAMO All it takes is extra eyes sometimes

Answer (score 3):

`i++` will add one to the value of `i` but *return the value of `i` before the increment*.  You don't want to do that.  You just want to return the value of `i` incremented by one.  To do this, just write:

```
dic[c] = i+1;
```

On a side note, you could do the whole thing using LINQ instead:

```
var dic = File.ReadAllText(path).GroupBy(c => c)
    .ToDictionary(group => group.Key, group => group.Count());
```

Comment: This LINQ answer is awesome!

Answer (score 2):

You want `dic[c] = i + 1;` or `dic[c] += 1` or `dic[c]++`. In your code the post increment operator is incrementing `i` after assignment takes place so it has no effect on the value of `dic[c]`.

Answer (score 2):

`dic[c]=i++;` translates to

```
dic[c] = i;
i = i++;
```

`i` isn't a reference value and thus the value of `i` placed inside the dictionary will not change after you increment it outside the dictionary.

Use `dic[c]++;` instead.

Answer (score 1):

This is because `i` gets incremented after being affected to `dict[c]`. Try this instead :

```
if(dic.ContainsKey(c))
{
    dic[c] += 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Dictionary<char, int> LetterCount(string textPath)
    {
        var dic = new Dictionary<char, int>();
        foreach (char c in System.IO.File.ReadAllText(textPath))
        {
            if (dic.ContainsKey(c))
                dic[c]++;
            else
                dic.Add(c, 1);
        }
        return dic;
    }
```

Then use like this:

```
var letters = LetterCount(@"C:\Text.txt");
// letters will contain the result
```